# Can a POST Contain Unencrypted, Sensitive Data?

Tags: php, http, post, passwords

Is it safe to send unencrypted, sensitive data such as a password via POST?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not safe, unless under SSL. Still perfectly possible, however.

Comment: Thank you :) So that means I will have to encrypt the password first then?

Comment: I'd just use SSL to encrypt your POST rather than devising your own encryption scheme.

Comment: As vcsjones said, just use SSL to encrypt it. You don't need to do anything, just the request will encrypt itself if you're using SSL. See this link, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication. It's not encrypted, but it is encoded. It's still not secure by any stretch.

Answer (score 4):

Define "safe". Without HTTPS, the method will not withstand attacks that eavesdrop on your connection: The data will be transferred unencrypted.

This is why you **must** use SSL when transmitting credit card data for example.

Different from GET, however, POST data will not be stored in the browser's URL history, nor in Proxy logs etc. It's still the method of choice for not totally sensitive log-in processes around the world.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is using POST vs GET.

Then no, POST does not add any further significant security benefits over using GET.

I'd recommend visiting the Open Web Application Security Project website, it offers lots of free (it's a not for profit organisation) helpful advice on security. http://www.owasp.org

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a popular and fresh example, facebook sends sensitive data over unencrypted connection.
Some very easy to install tool like [firesheep](http://codebutler.github.com/firesheep/) will get you all the data and grant you access to other peoples facebook accounts.
If you would have used SSL, this would not have happened.

Comment: Might also be worth pointing out Fiddler here, it's a non-browser dependant traffic listener, which is very powerful.